# Why $ \lim_{ n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n!}= \infty $ and not $1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I found on some online sites that
$$  \lim_{ n \to \infty}  \sqrt[n]{n!}= \infty $$

But I did not undertand ow they get it.

My attempt:
$$  \lim_{ n \to \infty}  \sqrt[n]{n!}= \lim_{ n \to \infty}  e^{\ln[ (n!)^{\frac1n}]} = \lim_{ n \to \infty}   e^{\frac1n \ln(n!)} = \lim_{ n \to \infty}   e^{ \frac{\ln(n)}{n} +\frac{\ln(n-1)}{n}+ \cdots } =   e^{ 0 +0+ \cdots }=   e^0 =1 $$

Comment: Do you know Stirling's approximation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: Is the  limit of $\frac 1 n+\frac 1 n+...+\frac 1 n $ equal to $0+0+...+0$? You cannot just take the limit for each term to get the limit of  a sum unless you have  a fixed number of terms.

Answer (score 2):

$n!  > (n/2)^{(n/2) };$

$(n!)^{(1/n)} >(n/2)^{(1/2)};$

Hence?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, each term of the sequence
$$
\frac{\ln n}{n} + \frac{\ln(n-1)}{n} + \cdots + \frac{\ln 1}{n}
$$
tends to zero, but you have $n$ of them. What is the sum of many small things? Well, it depends how many, and how small.

To solve this, you can indeed use Stirling's formula. Without it, a simple way is to see that, for $m_n = \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$
$$
n! = n \times (n-1) \times \cdots \times 1 \geq n \times (n-1) \times \cdots \times m_n \geq m_n^{m_n}, 
$$
and thus
$$
\frac{\ln (n!)}{n} \geq \frac{\ln(m_n^{m_n})}{n} = \frac{m_n}{n} \ln m_n \to + \infty,
$$
since $m_n/n \to 2$ and $\ln m_n \to + \infty$.